# t_body.children[k].appendChild(var) throws an error

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Consider the following js-loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<diff;++i){
        for (var j=0; j<old_col_num; ++j){
            var t_col = document.createElement("td");
            //the following line throws an error:
            t_body.children[old_row_num+1+i].appendChild(t_col);    
        }
}
```

The error message I get is the following:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined(…)
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. If I put in a fixed number instead of "old_row_num+1+i" there is no error (but I need the flexibility in my program).

UPDATE:

the whole function looks as follows:

```
function change_dim_r(diff) {

            var old_row_num = t_body.childElementCount;
            var old_col_num = t_body.children[0].childElementCount;

            for (var i=0; i<diff; ++i){
                var new_t_row = document.createElement("tr");
                t_body.appendChild(new_t_row);
            }

            for (var i=0;i<diff;++i){
                for (var j=0; j<old_col_num; ++j){
                    var t_col = document.createElement("td");
                    t_body.children[old_row_num+1+i].appendChild(t_col);    
                }
            }
 }
```

Comment: What is `diff` and what's `old_col_num`, and `t_body`?

Comment: There probably isn't a child so it's undefined...

Comment: Can I add screenshots here?

Comment: t_body is a variable containing the table body (i.e. var t_body = querySelector("tbody")). diff is the number of rows and columns that should be added (if diff==2, then 2 rows and 2 columns should be added). old_col_num is the number of columns in the table before any changed were made.

Comment: the table is a square, i.e. number of rows == number of columns;

Comment: in the code before the excerpt, I have increased the number of rows (tr tags) by diff. In this loop I want to add diff (e.g. 2) new td elements for every row in the table, whereby the number of rows in the table == (old_row_num+diff).

Comment: @Taplar The thing is that I have increased the number of rows before ... I will update the code excerpt to include this step as well

Comment: in the code before the excerpt, I have increased the number of rows (tr tags) by diff. In this loop I want to add columns for every new row in the table.
For example: my old table had 2 rows and 2 columns. Then I added 2 new rows (tr elements). Now I want to add 2 td elements for each new tr element. This last step (adding the td-elements to the respective tr-element) does not work

Comment: forget my second comment, I explained it wrong. The comment above is the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your old row number is inaccurate.

```
var old_row_num = t_body.children.childElementCount;
```

If you want the number of rows you wouldn't do `.children` there.

```js
function change_dim_r(diff) {

  var t_body = document.querySelector("tbody");
  var old_row_num = t_body.childElementCount;
  var old_col_num = t_body.children[0].childElementCount;

  for (var i = 0; i < diff; ++i) {
    var new_t_row = document.createElement("tr");
    t_body.appendChild(new_t_row);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < t_body.childElementCount; ++i) {
    var t_row = t_body.children[i];
    
    for (var j = t_row.childElementCount; j < t_body.childElementCount; ++j) {
      var t_col = document.createElement("td");
      t_row.appendChild(t_col);
    }
  }
}

change_dim_r(10);
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you are right, i corrected it ... but I still get the same error message

Comment: your code snippet works .... my code still doesn't ... I dont get that

Comment: If you look at the loop that creates the td you will see i am doing that part differently.  I am not using old_row_num or old_col_num any where.  I'm simply going off of the t_body row count and for each row as long as there are less cells than there are rows, i'm creating a new cell.  If you want to debug your original loop then console log out the 'i's and 'j's you are using as well as the sums you are using for the indexes.  Though it is notable to say that your loop of 'j' isn't using 'j' any where.